# phrase structured grammar

Tags: discrete-mathematics

find a phrase structure grammar for each of these languages:

1. the set consisting of the bit strings 10, 01, and 101
2. the set of bit strings that start with 00 and end with one or more 1's
3. the set of bit strings consisting of an even number of 1's followed by a final 0
4. the set of bit strings that have neither two consecutive 0's nor two consecutive 1's

I have no idea how to start this. A step in the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you supposed to use BNF, or what?

Comment: Well this is the exact directions from my textbook. I don't know what you mean by BNF

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form is used to describe grammars. Doesn't the textbook present any method?

Comment: @Lehs: It’s very unlikely that BNF is wanted; for the standard notation for phrase-structure grammars see my answer.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: I learned from your example.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll do (3) as an example to get you started. You want $G=\langle N,\Sigma,P,S\rangle$, where $N$ is the set of non-terminal symbols, $\Sigma$ is the set of terminal symbols, $P$ is the set of productions, and $S$ is the initial symbol, which must be in $N$. Clearly $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$: these are the symbols that are allowed to appear in the words of the language.

We want to generate any even number of ones followed by a single zero. Suppose that we have a production $S\to 11S$, where $S$ is the initial symbol; if we apply this production $3$ times, say, we get the following derivation.

$$S\Longrightarrow 11S\Longrightarrow 1111S\Longrightarrow 111111S\;.$$

You should be able to see that if we apply it $n$ times, where $n$ is a non-negative integer, we get $$\underbrace{11\ldots11}_{2n}S$$ or, in the more usual notation, $1^{2n}S$. Thus, we can generate any even number of ones in this way, but we’ll still have an $S$ on the end instead of the zero that we want. That’s easily fixed: add a production $S\to 0$. Then after generating $1^{2n}S$ by $n$ applications of $S\to 11S$, we can apply $S\to 0$ to get $1^{2n}0$. We can do this for any integer $n\ge 0$, so we get all words of the form $\{1^{2n}0:n\ge 0\}$, which is the desired language. And it should be pretty clear that we can’t generate anything else.

Our grammar is therefore

$$\big\langle\{S\},\{0,1\},\{S\to 11S,S\to 0\},S\big\rangle\;:$$

$N=\{S\}$, because our only non-terminal symbol is $S$, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, $P=\{S\to 11S,S\to 0\}$, and $S$ is our initial symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e not supposed to guess when answer, but anyway I guess on (1):

$\{S\to10,S\to01,S\to101\}$